# SwiftUI String conform Identifiable seems not correct

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using an array in a `List`, in the `List` there's a `ForEach`, like:

```
struct AView: View {

    @State var foo: [String] = ["a", "b", "c"]

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            List {
                ForEach(foo.indices) { index in
                    Text(foo[index])
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This works well, then I want to add a button to insert new items:

```
   List {
            ForEach(foo.indices) { index in
                Text(foo[index])
            }
        }
        Button("Add") {
            foo.append("foo")
        }
    }
```

Then I got the error, which is obviously:

```
ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, Text> count (4) != its initial count (3). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!
```

Here mentioned

`Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)`

I can use  `ForEach(foo.indices, id:\.self)` which solved the issue.

I also want to try `Identifiable`, and don't use `id:\.self` in the `ForEach`, `ForEach(foo.indices)`.

I added extension to String like:

```
extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self }
}
```

But still got the same issue. Any thing I miss-understood? thanks!

**EDIT**

According to the comment @New Dev, as I literal `indices`, so I added extension to `Int`:

```
extension Int: Identifiable {
    public var id: Int { self }
}
```

still doesn't work.

Comment: You did `ForEach(foo.indices, id:\.self)` and it worked. Is there still a problem?

Comment: I see... you conformed `String` to `Identifiable` but you actually iterate over indices of the array (which happen to be `Int`). You could just do `ForEach(foo) { fooStr in ... }`

Comment: yes, `ForEach(foo)` works if I don't need `index` but I need index, I tried conform `Identifiable` to `Int` still no luck.

Comment: My bad.. `foo.indices` is actually `Range<Int>`, not `[Int]`.... why doesn't `ForEach(foo.indices, id:\.self)` work for you?

Comment: `ForEach(Array(foo.indices))` works when you extend `Int` to be `Identifiable`.

Comment: As you see in the error message, the `ForEach(_:content:)` completion should only be used for *constant* data. You need to use the id: \.self completion for *dynamic* data.

Comment: @NewDev hi  thanks, it works when convert it to `[Int]`, I just want to figure out how to make the `Identifiable` way also works. @vacawama thanks too, it works!

Comment: @vacawama, actually, `Range<Int>` conforms to `RandomAccessCollection`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ForEach` has multiple `init` overloads.

`init(Range<Int>, content: (Int) -> Content)` only works with a constant range - hence the error.

`init(Data, content: (Data.Element) -> Content)` requires `Data` to conform to `RandomAccessCollection` of `Identifiable` elements. That's the one you want to use.

The problem is that your `RandomAccessCollection` (to which `Range<Int>` conforms) is a collection of `Int` elements.

Though you can conform `Int` to `Identifiable`, this would still not work. It would still use the first `ForEach.init` with a `Range<Int>` parameter, because of method overload preference - i.e. `Range<Int>` matches the more specific `init` with `Range<Int>` parameter, rather than the less specific `init` with `RandomAccessCollection`.

---

So, your choices are:

1. Use the third `init(Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, content: (Data.Element) -> Content)` by explicitly specifying the `id`.

```
ForEach(foo.indices, id:\.self) { index in 
}
```

2. Convert to `Array<Int>` and conform `Int: Identifiable`:

```
extension Int: Identifiable { var id: Self { self } }

ForEach(Array(foo.indices)) { index in 
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of returning `Self` when extending `Int`?

Comment: @LeoDabus it's no difference same thing.

Comment: As opposed to what? `Int`? It's a matter of taste, no?

Comment: Thats what I mean. It is pointless. Taste? It will always be an `Int`.

Comment: @LeoDabus, I prefer that because it works exactly the same for any other `Hashable`-conforming type, and I think it conveys the semantic intent better.... in any case, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I do use `Self` as well sometimes when conforming structures to a protocol like `Comparable` just because it is shorter to write. But the main purpose of using `Self` as return type is when extending a protocol.